# Object Declaration in if Condition -  logic break point  in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, object, conditional-statements

Object Declaration in if Condition -  logic break:

```
If mycondition = True Then
   Dim objrpt As New CrystalReport1
 Else
   Dim objrpt As New CrystalReport2
End If
```

**objrpt.SetDataSource(ds.tables("xxx"))**

I am getting an error in above line says:
objrpt is not declared it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

I agree it may be inaccessible if the condition doesn't met - but here
if it doesn't met it will take CrystalReport2 know ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your variable must be declared outside the `If` statement. Variables declared inside an `If` statement cannot be accessed from outside.

```
Dim objrpt As ReportDocument
If mycondition = True Then
   objrpt = New CrystalReport1
 Else
   objrpt = New CrystalReport2
End If
objrpt.SetDataSource(ds.tables("xxx"))
```

Comment: No its not working. i tried to create an object for crystalreport - but it does not allow me - and i didn't find any option for just crystalreport but we can create for crystalreport document/file like crystalreport1 or 2

Comment: Below code working fine - but its funny in logic :-)

If GLB_SelectedRPT = "3B" Then
 Dim objrpt As New CommissionRpt3B
 objrpt.SetDataSource(StrongDS.Tables("mytempcomm"))
 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objrpt
Else
 Dim objrpt As New CommissionRpt3BPlus
 objrpt.SetDataSource(StrongDS.Tables("mytempcomm"))
 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objrpt
End If

Comment: I'm not familiar with crystal report but there might be a common interface to CrystalReportViewer1 and CrystalReportViewer2, for example ICrystalReport. In that case the `objrpt` variable should be of this type. If they are two distinct types then you cannot really expect to use both in the same variable.

Comment: From what I found on the web, seems like the base class for reports is ReportDocument. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Below code working fine - but its funny in logic :-)

```
If GLB_SelectedRPT = "3B" Then
   Dim objrpt As New CommissionRpt3B
   objrpt.SetDataSource(StrongDS.Tables("mytempcomm"))
   CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objrpt
Else
   Dim objrpt As New CommissionRpt3BPlus
   objrpt.SetDataSource(StrongDS.Tables("mytempcomm"))
   CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objrpt
End If
```

Regards,
Sensa

Answer (score 0):

Or you simply use the below code I find it more convenient to use.

```
Dim objrpt 
If mycondition = True Then
   objrpt = New CrystalReport1
   objrpt.SetDataSource(ds.tables("xxx"))
 Else
   objrpt = New CrystalReport2
objrpt.SetDataSource(ds.tables("xxx"))
End If
```

Regards,
Biju